# Trying to re-implement strcat and getting wrong results

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why i can't put `*a++` in this while `loop` and get what i want ,( i saw in book for `C` that this form can be used), but i got something else in output.

```
void strcat(char *a, char *b)
{
   while( *a != '\0'){
    a++;
   }
   for ( ;*b != '\0' ; *a++ = *b++);
}
```

When i checked what is current value, after this `while` loop ,for *a it print at both ways (up and down) same value and it is `0`. But when i print my result is correct only for up way.
Why i can't do something like this?

```
while( *a++ != '\0');
```

Comment: Try: while (*(a++) != '\0')

Comment: please consider rewording, it is difficult to understand

Comment: @zam664 `*a++` means `*(a++)` already

Answer (score 4):

```
while( *a != '\0'){
    a++;
```

and

```
while( *a++ != '\0');
```

are not identical.

The first one increments `a` as long as it does not point to the terminator,
the second increments `a` and repeats that as long as `a` did not point to the terminator before the increment.

The difference is exactly one increment of `a`, making the second code an off-by-one-error.

You have a similar problem with the second loop:

```
for ( ;*b != '\0' ; *a++ = *b++);
```

It checks whether it reached the terminator, and otherwise copies one element from `b` to `a`.
Thus, it does not copy the terminator!

Change to:

```
while((*a++ = *b++)) {}
```

(Double-parentheses to suppress compiler-warning about possibly erroneous assignment in conditional expression.)

Additional tip:
Make intentional empty statements more obvious, use `{}`.

Also, when you re-implement the standard-library, [consider following its definition](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html), return the result-string.
Final code:

```
char* strcat(char *a, const char *b)
{
    char* ret = a;
    while(*a)
        a++;
    while((*a++ = *b++))
        {}
    return ret;
}
```